# Bash script not running tclsh

Tags: bash, tcl

I am able to run bash on a remote home properly. I have TCL installed on the remote host but am not able to run TCL. When I run this script, I get no errors.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX << EOF
echo "Connected";
echo "CD TO ~";
cd ~;
echo "Create text file";

script='
        set data "This is some test data.\n"
        set filename "test.txt"
        set fileId [open $filename "w"]
        puts -nonewline $fileId $data
        close $fileId
exit 0'

tclsh << HERE
$script
echo "Exit";

exit
EOF
```

Comment: btw, you're also missing a `HERE`. Presumably that should be just before the `echo "Exit"`. That one you _don't_ want to quote, since you're using that heredoc as a POSIX-sh equivalent to a herestring.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy Everything is working great now :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heredocs expand variables inside them by default, so your `[open $filename "w"]` is changed to `open  "w"]` (and similar changes elsewhere) unless you have a `filename` variable exported in your outer script. If you don't want that expansion to occur, quote your sigil:

```
ssh root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX <<'EOF'

script='content'

# intentionally not quoting this sigil, since in this case expansion is desired
tclsh <<HERE
$script
HERE

EOF
```

Comment: And its always the simplest of things

Comment: I think it's easier at this point to start using separate files for things. Having everything all in one is all very well, but the confusion inevitably mounts after a while…